# Cannot set value of ListView Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, web, nested

I am having trouble setting the value of a textbox inside a nested listview (listview inside a lsitview). What I am trying to do is pull values of two textboxes (which is working fine), multiply them together, and set that value to the third textbox (where I am having the trouble).

here is the listview setup that I have:

```
<asp:ListView ID="LV_Tickets" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" DataSourceID="SQL_Tickets" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" OnPreRender="LV_Tickets_PreRender" DataKeyNames="TicketNum">
<SelectedItemTemplate>

     <asp:ListView ID="LV_TicketProd" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ChargeID" DataSourceID="SQL_TicketProducts" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" OnPreRender="LV_TicketProd_PreRender" OnItemInserted="LV_TicketProd_ItemInserted" OnItemInserting="LV_TicketProd_ItemInserting" OnItemUpdated="LV_TicketProd_ItemUpdated" OnItemUpdating="LV_TicketProd_ItemUpdating">
<InsertItemTemplate>

     <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="HoursOrCubesTextBox" runat="server" style="height: 20px; width: 165px;" Text='<%# Bind("HoursOrCubes") %>' OnTextChanged="HoursOrCubes_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
     </td>
     <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="RateTextBox" runat="server" style="height: 20px; width: 120px;" Text='<%# Bind("Rate") %>' OnTextChanged="Rate_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
     </td>
     <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="LineTotalTextBox" runat="server" style="height: 20px; width: 120px;" Text='<%# Bind("LineTotal") %>' />
     </td>

</ InsertItemTemplate>

</ SelectedItemTemplate>
```

The current way that I am getting the values from `HoursOrCubesTextBox` and `RateTextBox` is:

```
protected void HoursOrCubesTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView LV_TicketProd = (ListView)Session["TicketProd"];
    TextBox HoursOrCubesTextBox = (TextBox)(LV_TicketProd.InsertItem.FindControl("HoursOrCubesTextBox"));

    string HoC = HoursOrCubesTextBox.Text //This here is getting the value from the textbox.
}
```

But when I try to do the opposite to set the value of the textbox nothing happens:

```
TextBox LineTotalTextBox = (TextBox)(LV_TicketProd.InsertItem.FindControl("LineTotalTextBox"));
LineTotalTextBox.Text = FinalValue; //FinalValue is the two values multiplied together.
```

I have check that the values coming from the textboxes are correct, and that when I multiply them together I get a value that is an integer. So I am not entirely sure why I cannot set the value of the LineTotalTextBox. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this problem. What I did was set the two textboxes `HoursOrCubes` and `Rate` to autopostback, then did the multiplication and setting of the textbox in the onload function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try reading & writing into the item template.   That's the `ListView`'s job.

Read & write the data source which the ListView is bound to.

I'd show examples if what I mean, but I can't figure your code.... Are you filling the ListView from an SQL db or from User input?

Comment: The ListViews are connected to a SQL Data Source that is connected to a database. But users can add data into the database through the ListView. And I want to change the value of the textbox in the listview before the data is inserted into the database.

Comment: DO your work in the ListView's OnItemUpdating event.

Comment: Doesn't the OnItemUpdating event only trigger when you UPDATE not INSERT the value?

Comment: The text boxes are still blank after an insert.  Then the user changes them, causing the UPDATE.

Comment: I just gave that a try and the Item Updating event handler does not fire at all. These textboxes are in the InsertItemTemplate, and I am trying to update the textbox before the record is inserted.